# React Native TabNavigator change TabStyle to follow according to the text

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator, react-native-tabnavigator

I am using expo v27.0, react native 0.55 and I as you can see in the picture that the tab have somewhat a fixed width like a default width from the tab navigation, and the text wrap into three lines, I want the text to be in 1 line and nowrap, and i have tried styling (flexWrap: 
'nowrap', flex: 1) in TabStyle, LabelStyle in TabBarOptions, but still can't get the tab to have the width according to the text inside the tab.

I populate the text for the tabs dynamically from json using fetch, therefore all tabs will have different width according to the text. How to I make the tab to follow the width of the text ?

[image]

All answers are greatly welcomed.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Solved, turns out just need to set the width to auto as follows:

```
tabBarOptions: {
    tabStyle: {
        width: 'auto'
    }
}
```

Comment: @OliverDixon yes, i hide the underline, still could not find a method to make the underline length correct

Answer (score 0):

You can use render label in render header and in that you can return your Text component and Text is having `numberOfLines` props that will be 1 and it will add `...` at end of the text after one line.

Check example snippet:

```
_renderLabel = props => {
    let preparedProps = {
      style: {
        fontFamily: fonts.Regular,
        marginVertical: 8
      },
      fontType: props.focused ? "Medium" : "Light"
    };
    return (
      <Text
        {...preparedProps}
        numberOfLines={1}
        ref={ref => {
          ref && this.props.addAppTourTarget(ref, props.route.key);
        }}
      >
        {props.route.type === "free" && this.state.is_premium_member
          ? this.labels.premium
          : props.route.title}
      </Text>
    );
  };
  _renderHeader = props => (
    <TabBar
      {...props}
      bounces={true}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: colors.cardBlue
      }}
      indicatorStyle={{
        backgroundColor: colors.radicalRed,
        height: 1,
        borderRightWidth: initialLayout.width * 0.1,
        borderLeftWidth: initialLayout.width * 0.1,
        borderColor: colors.cardBlue
      }}
      tabStyle={{
        padding: 0,
        borderTopColor: "transparent",
        borderWidth: 0
      }}
      renderLabel={this._renderLabel}
    />
  );
  _handleIndexChange = index => this.setState({ index });
  _renderScene = ({ route, focused }) => {
    switch (route.key) {
      case "a":
        return <One {...this.props} route={route} focused={focused} />;
      case "b":
        return (
          <Two {...this.props} isSeries={true} focused={focused} />
        );
      case "c":
        return <Three {...this.props} route={route} focused={focused} />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };
```